# Template logic not working in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In the effort to try to keep things clean I'm trying to get my css/js loaded correctly based on the Wordpress template.

Trying to do a check if it's not the file `menu_and_footer.php` then run those functions. No matter what I seem to do it always goes to the `else` when it's on the `Menu and Footer` template.

I also tried to check `if front page` or `is homepage` and still doesn't like the checks. Am I missing something?

Both `functions.php` and the `menu_and_footer.php` are both in the same root folder.

```
if (is_page_template('menu_and_footer.php')){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'side_projects_css');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'side_projects_scripts');
}else{
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'main_css');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
}
```

Comment: What is `menu_and_footer.php` supposed to be, the name doesn't sound like that was actually a full page template - but rather only a template _part_, that gets embedded into other templates? I don't think `is_page_template` works for the latter.